# Is "I would be happy if I can return the favor” grammatically correct?

Tags: modal-verbs, conditionals, could-modal

> You have been a tremendous help to me and I would be very happy if I ***can*** return the favor in the future.

Let's consider that someone has helped me in the past and I am talking to this person and now I am telling them that "I will be happy if I can help you in the future". Does the above written sentence convey the same meaning and is it grammatically, especially when considering conditional sentences, correct?

I checked conditional sentence type 2 but that meaning is not what I want to convey by this sentence.
Conditional type II:

> "You have been a tremendous help to me and I would be very happy if I ***could*** return the favor."

=> it means that I won't be able to return the favor. But that is not what I am trying to say here.

Comment: I might have said "I be happy...if I could..." There are more than 4 types of conditionals: the zero, first, second and third are the ones that are most commonly taught to ESL learners.

Comment: I think the more idiomatic way is "I would be happy to return the favor". (to me, Midwest USA)

Answer (score 1):

Both "can" and "could" convey the same sense to me. I would like to return the favor. That may or may not be possible. The "*would* be happy" conveys the uncertainty.